# Ruby TCPServer strange behavior in writing to client

Tags: ruby, tcpserver

I'm creating a Ruby gem named EmeraldCutter which is, essentially, a very simple TCP server. It happens that I detected a very strange behavior and I'd be very glad if someone could give me some clue about this.

As you may see by the code below, it starts a new Thread for each request received, grabs the message sent to the server, separate its parameters and stores them in a hash and then writes to the client a list with the elements of this hash in a list of the form

```
key => parameter
```

Then when I run this server and navigate to `http://localhost:4321/something` my browser should receive something like

```
http_verb => GET
query_string => /something
http_version => HTTP/1.1
host => localhost:4321
connection => keep-alive
cache_control => max-age=0
accept => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
upgrade_insecure_requests => 1
user_agent => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
dnt => 1
accept_encoding => gzip, deflate, sdch
accept_language => pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr-CA;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2
```

but nothing is displayed and when I visit the Network tab at the developer's console to examine this request, I see a message saying `Failed to load response data`.

Here is my code:

**lib/emerald.rb**

```
require "emeraldcutter/auxiliary"
require "emeraldcutter/version"

module EmeraldCutter

  def self.start
    require 'socket'

    server = TCPServer.new 4321
    loop do 
      Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
        message = client.recvmsg[0]
        request = get_request_parameters(message)
        request.each{ |k,v| client.puts "#{k} => #{v}" }
        client.close
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def self.http_verb(msg_token)
    msg_token.split(' ')[0]
  end

  def self.http_protocol(msg_token)
    msg_token.split(' ')[2]
  end

  def self.query_string(msg_token)
    msg_token.split(' ')[1]
  end

  def self.get_request_parameters(message)
    result = Hash.new
    lines = message.split("\n");
    first_line = lines.shift
    result['http_verb'] = http_verb(first_line)
    result['query_string'] = query_string(first_line)
    result['http_version'] = http_protocol(first_line)
    lines.each{ |line|
      key_value = line.split(': ')
      key = EmeraldCutter::Auxiliary.normalize_hash_key(key_value[0].strip)
      result[key] = key_value[1].strip if not key.empty?
    }
    result
  end

end
```

**lib/emeraldcutter/auxiliary.rb**

```
module EmeraldCutter
  module Auxiliary

    def self.normalize_hash_key(key)
      key.downcase.tr('-','_')
    end

  end
end
```

This wouldn't be so strange. But things get really weird when I add `client.puts "Teste"` to the Thread block like this

```
    server = TCPServer.new 4321
    loop do 
      Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
        client.puts "Test"
        message = client.recvmsg[0]
        request = get_request_parameters(message)
        request.each{ |k,v| client.puts "#{k} => #{v}" }
        client.close
      end
    end
  end
```

and then it works perfectly well and I get

```
Test
http_verb => GET
query_string => /something
http_version => HTTP/1.1
host => localhost:4321
connection => keep-alive
cache_control => max-age=0
accept => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
upgrade_insecure_requests => 1
user_agent => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
dnt => 1
accept_encoding => gzip, deflate, sdch
accept_language => pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr-CA;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2
```

Have you ever seen something like this? If so, what is the reason?

Comment: Are you sure when you make the change it starts working _in your browser_? You’re not sending back a valid HTTP response, which would explain the “Failed to load response data” error, and adding that extra line doesn’t turn it into a valid response. Are you looking at the response directly with something like Telnet?

Comment: I'll try that, @matt. But as far as I know, one may send ANY response with puts and it will be written to the client, in this case the browser. There are examples here at SO where one just wrote `puts "#{Date.now}"` with no headers and it worked. I tried something like this myself, sending back just the "Test" word and it worked fine.

Comment: I tried it and got just "Test" from the Telnet, since it just don't send a message header. This is perfectly fine, but does not explain this behavior when the message header is sent.

Comment: You’re right – it looks like the browser will just display the response contents if it detects it’s not valid HTTP. I wouldn’t have expected that! I suspect that in your first case the browser initially thinks it’s looking at a valid response (possibly due to the http at the start), but is unable to parse it so errors out. In the second case it knows right away that it isn’t dealing with a normal response so just displays the result.

Comment: It’s not obvious what the criteria for detecting a valid response are, and it seems to vary across browsers. Firefox and Safari both display your first example OK. In Chrome, adding `Test` results in everything being shown, but just adding `Tes` still gives the error.

Comment: (Sorry – I reworded one of my comments slightly, and needed to delete and recreate them to do so, which crossed with one of your comments, so things might look a bit out of order).

Comment: No problem. I'll try that!